# Simple jQuery AJAX XML load not working

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm just trying to load some simple XML data using AJAX, but it has no effect, and I can't for the life of me find the error. Any help is appreciated. Here's the code:

For the page:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Big Skinny Wallet Helper</title>
 <style>
 #nav
 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 width:300px;
 background-color:#b0e0e6;
 }
 #content
 {
 position:absolute;
 left: 300px;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="nav">
 This is text on the left.
 <form>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" id="male" value="male">Male<br />
 <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" id="female" value="female">Female<br     />
 </form>
 </div>

<div id="content">
This is the main content area.
</div>

<div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get('wallets.xml', function(data) {
    $('#content').empty();
    $(data).find('wallet').each(function() {
        var $wallet = $(this);
        var html = '<div class="wallet">';
        html += '<h3 class="name">' + $wallet.attr('name');
        html += '</h3>';
        html += '</div>';
        $('#content').append($(html));
    });
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wallets>
<wallet name="Compact Sport" material="nylon" gender="male">
    <description>
        This is the latest bi-fold wallet in our series of super thin and      light sport wallets featuring four card pockets. Since most people only use 4-6 cards     regularly, just use the front two pockets for those cards and stack & store all those other cards in the hidden 2 storage pockets--go minimalist by keeping your material layers to a minimum. The favorite thin wallet used every single day by the Big Skinny founder.
    </description>
</wallet>
<wallet name="Curve" material="nylon" gender="male">
    <description>
        Front pocket wallet-carriers, this is the model for you! We hate the state the obvious, but hey, it's fun: the curve is designed with two-rounded edges to fit neatly in your front or back pants pocket. Crafted from tough, machine-washable, nylon micro-fiber, this ultra thin wallet can hold about 20 plastic cards and cash. The pockets and billfold area are lined with a rubbery coating to help prevent your goods from sliding out: smart!
    </description>
</wallet>
</wallets>
```

Comment: What errors do you actually get? Please describe your problem.

Comment: check your console for any errors

Comment: The problem seems to be with the xml data, it is giving an parse eror

Comment: Checkout http://plnkr.co/edit/8EtCsK2WGwUYtMXtqgdE?p=preview

Comment: The error in my console is as follows:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/bigskinny/Desktop/Brendan/jquery-example/my-demo/wallets.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

But the file is definitely there and full of data...

Comment: @FelixKling can you find any problem with the xml data source in the above demo

Comment: The error means that the browser is not allowed to access the file, because of the same origin policy. You cannot make Ajax calls when you open the page locally.

Comment: ok, it is because you are using local file system. Use a web server like tomcat and check it again

Comment: When I use a webserver (Apache) it still doesn't work, and console gives the error:
TableManager::findTables() content.scripts.c.js:11

Comment: Not sure what you mean by static - it's just a normal xml file I made in a text editor and uploaded to the server like I would any other file

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not validating.  `&` should be `&amp;`.

For future reference, try [this validator](http://validator.w3.org/check).

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Sweet.  If you are generating that XML file, you may consider [HtmlEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx) the data to prevent this from happening again.